# SQL Buddy + https(ssl) + nginx unable to login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, nginx, webserver

I am setting up my very own server for the first time! Following the steps on the Ars Technica guide (http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/web-served-part-4-get-your-database-on/).

However, when I try to login to SqlBuddy, I get immediately redirected back to the login page. I know that it can detect an incorrect login because I get an error message.

There are no errors in my php error log. I am also able to successfully see the phpinfo() page, so I know my php is setup properly.

Any ideas? It seems like not many people have problems with SQL buddy, I have tried googling and searching on here for similar problems.

Thanks! 
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Investigating, I found that the sessions were expiring instantly.

Memcached was not configured properly, the typo in my case was in php-sock.conf.
The correct text shoulds be:
server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;